# curl from Write_http plugin of collectd is not working

Tags: ssl, curl, splunk, collectd

I am trying to enable to Write_http plugin in collectd for Splunk, the problem is when I try to curl externally

```
curl http://10.xx.xxx.x:8088/services/collector/raw  -H "Authorization: Splunk 2c396ad4-f518-416f-83cd-e37596228792" -d {"test":"value"}
```

It works. But when I do the same in
 collectd plugin

```
<Plugin write_http>
<Node "node-http-1">
URL "http://10.xx.xxx.x:8088/services/collector/raw?channel=2c396ad4-f518-416f-83cd-e37596228792"
Header "Authorization: Splunk 2c396ad4-f518-416f-83cd-e37596228792"
Format "JSON"
Metrics true
StoreRates true
```

I get

```
[error] write_http plugin: curl_easy_perform failed with status 56: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

is it because of the curl version of collectd?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the port in global settings in http data inputs in splunk.
It must be 8080 by default. Change the port in collect.conf accordingly in write_http plugin.

Hope it works for you!